# Java setText make application error

Tags: java, android, exception

I have simple application in Android
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/id_txt"
    android:text="go"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and TestActivity.java

```
package test.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_txt);
        t.setText("gone");
    }
}
```

and after executing in android emulator a recive message `The application Test has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again later`, but why ??

Comment: You need to grab the logs from the device or emulator: "adb logcat" should do the trick, there will be a stack trace in the log.  Or you can use the "Show View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat" view in Eclipse with the device connected.

Comment: LogCat show `09-28 19:44:59.724: ERROR/dalvikvm(1727): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied` so how to change permissions ?

Comment: did you remember to declare your activity in the manifest?

Comment: If U are talking about `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I havent done nothig. Pleas write what should be done

Comment: Please include more of the log file and a copy of your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Strange after restarting Eclipse it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't overriding the `onCreate(...)` method correctly. It should be as follows...

```
// NOTE: Use @Override and also the method is 'protected' and not 'public'
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_txt);
    t.setText("gone");
}
```

Comment: Its default structur which was make be eclipse

Comment: Well eclipse made it incorrectly... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)